# Microsoft graph API: /me/drive/root/search - no path to found file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have problem with graph API. I'm making search component in React. Of course there can be many files with same name so I need to display path to it also. Problem is with this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='book')
```

I noticed that when I'm searching for all drive elements I receive path to file. But when I'm using /me/drive endpoint to search for only my files there is no path in parentReference.
The only option to get path is making second request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{parent_reference_id}
```

Is there any solution for this? I tried expanding parentReference but it's saying that it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you try to get the path of an item you can use the /Items/{itemId} endpoint that gives the ParentReference property with the path in it.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/Items/{Itemid}
```

[image]

In your case as you are searching for book file, pull the id from there and use the above query to get the path.